# VIP Alert Notification

Tags: iphone, email, notifications, do-not-disturb

Is there a way to set up VIP Alert Notifications to allow the sound even when my iPhone is on silent? I want to be able to receive notification of VIP emails during the night, but do not want the bother of a notification from someone calling/texting me.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 11, you can only allow *phone calls* from specific contacts through a global silent mode (**Do Not Disturb**).

This is defined under Settings → Do Not Disturb → Allow Calls From.

There is no exception list for *Emails* or *Messages* yet, even though this feature has been requested for years.